# Mapping DNA relationships on paper

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis

I have recently started digging into my DNA matches.

I have several closely related matches. I was born in Montana and my grandma was married to a man who has no biological relationship to me. However my mom has lied about who my father is my entire life.

The result was unbelievable I have DNA matches to my non bio grandpa's first wife who had 6 siblings and 4 kids. I first went straight to my grandma's grandchildren luckily one had done the same Ancestry test as me. We had no DNA match but shared matches.

I am 75% 1st cousins with a female and even closer to her cousin and 2 others that are above 500 segments all related.

I have most of the grandparent's, great grandparent's and sibling's names. I just do not know how to map it on paper.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Also I have reached out to several people and only a few will even respond and I have been blocked from seeing matches with a few as well.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Here you are referring to some people who are still alive by name, so we will have to redact their names.  See our Privacy Policy in the [help] for ways you may be able to keep those details displayed.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is a McGuire Method Diagram.

[image]

This technique of charting DNA matches was developed by Lauren McGuire in 2016.

Lauren wrote a guest post on Blaine Bettinger's blog in 2017 describing her technique.
["GUEST POST: The McGuire Method – Simplified Visual DNA Comparisons - The Genetic Genealogist"](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/2017/03/19/guest-post-the-mcguire-method-simplified-visual-dna-comparisons/)

"This visual summary, allows you to ... determine which cM relationships do or don’t fit properly. Conversely, if you have a match that you know fits somewhere, but haven’t been able to place, knowing the cM match and the likely location where they belong can bring a seeker much closer to the proper spot in a family."